# Segmentation Fault in my ArrayList class reallocation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, realloc

For learning purposes, I'm attempting to create a primitive `ArrayList` class with the ability to add elements and resize itself when needed. Currently, I managed to create a constructor and overload the array access operator as well as add an `append` function to add elements to the back of the array. However, once the `realloc` is triggered, the program crashes with `Segmentation Fault: 11`. Oddly, though, if I change my code, the first time I execute it there is no segmentation fault; only when rerunning the executable does it fail, so I am suspicious my `free()` call is not working properly. All elements until the reallocation appear to be successfully added.

I have my class defined in a .cpp file because template definitions are unable to be split into a header and other file.

structures.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T> class ArrayList {
    private:
        T* pointer;
        unsigned short space;
    public:
        ArrayList();
        ~ArrayList();
        T& operator[](unsigned short index);
        const T& operator[](unsigned short index) const; 
        unsigned short length;
        void append(T element);
};

template<typename T> ArrayList<T>::ArrayList() {
    length = 0;
    space = 10;
    pointer = (T*)malloc(space*sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T> ArrayList<T>::~ArrayList() {
    free(pointer);
}

template<typename T> T& ArrayList<T>::operator[](unsigned short index) {
    if (index > length) throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds.");
    return *(pointer + sizeof(T)*index);
}

template<typename T> void ArrayList<T>::append(T element) {
    if (length == space) {
        space *= 2;
        pointer = (T*)realloc(pointer, sizeof(T)*space);
    }
    *(pointer + sizeof(T)*length) = element;
    ++length;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "structures.cpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ArrayList<unsigned> arr;
    int l = 11;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Current index: " << i << std::endl;
        arr.append(i);
    }
    std::cout << "Finished writing to array" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Index: " << i << " Value: " << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Current index: 0
Current index: 1
Current index: 2
Current index: 3
Current index: 4
Current index: 5
Current index: 6
Current index: 7
Current index: 8
Current index: 9
Current index: 10
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Besides the already-posted answer. your array template class [violates the Rule Of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three); additionally it results in undefined behavior for non-POD `T`s, but that's not relevant to the reason for your actual crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here (in your `append` function):

```
*(pointer + sizeof(T)*length) = element;
```

You forget that `pointer` is a pointer to (the first element of) an array of `T` elements, and not an array of bytes. What you're doing is (exactly) equal to

```
pointer[sizeof(T)*length] = element;
```

which is clearly wrong and can easily be out of bounds and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The correct way is simply

```
pointer[length] = element;
```

Or if you're forced to use explicit pointer arithmetic (I see no other reason)

```
*(pointer + length) = element;
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! But is the undefined behavior the reason why it occasionally lead to a correctly functioning program?

Comment: @NeilA. One of the possibilities of UB (Undefined Behavior) is to seemingly work okay.